# Where can I get the CUR files for the Firefox cursor values?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, mouse-cursor

I'm using some of Firefox's specially-defined values for cursor, in particular

```
-moz-zoom-in
-moz-zoom-out
-moz-grab
-moz-grabbing
```

In order to display these on other browsers, I'd like to deploy the equivalent CUR files — but I can't seem to find these online, or in my copy of Firefox.

Anyone know where these are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the files by downloading the [Firefox source](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial).

I had installed [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) this morning, just to check it out.  Good thing!

Answer (score 1):

They can be most easily found here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/widget/windows/res/

or else here: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/ and then click "widget" -> "windows" -> "res", click "file" next to the file you want, and click "raw" to download.